# Swift: Generic Class Type Requirement Unfulfillable by Class-Only Protocol

Tags: swift, class, generics, swift-protocols

Say, I have a structure with a generic type parameter that requires a class type:

```swift
struct Foo<T: AnyObject> {}
```

As expected, I cannot use this structure with value types, but it works with class types:

```swift
// Error: 'Foo' requires that 'String' be a class type
let _  = Foo<String>()

// Working.
let _ = Foo<NSString>()
```

If I define a class-only protocol:

```swift
protocol Bar: AnyObject {}
```

I cannot, however, use the structure with this protocol:

```swift
// Error: 'Foo' requires that 'any Bar' be a class type
let _ = Foo<Bar>()
```

Why is that? And how would I work around this?

Comment: A generic requires a concrete type. How you work around depends on your *specific* use case.

Comment: @Sulthan That was what I thought to but if you remove the `AnyObject` requirement from the `Foo` declaration, `struct Foo<T> {}`, then the last line compiles.